# Switch on the fill between plots only if a condition is met

Tags: if-statement, plot, switch-statement, pine-script

Ok. So I'm trying to make a switch for the fill in between the plots.

So that way, the fill doesn't always show up but only when I want it, and only between the plots I want, not all the ones that are there.

The first step, I thought, was to make a switch for the fill-- true or false. And then use the "if" later, as shown below.

```
//@version=3
study("fill ema test")

//---input switches for the emas

ei8 = input(true, title="ema 8")
ei100 = input(true, title="ema 100")
ei200 = input(true, title="ema 200")

//---input switch attempts for the fills. 
// ef8 = input(false, title= "fill e8/e100")
// ef100 = input(false, title= "fill e100/e200")
// ef200 = input(false, title="fill e8/e200")

efp= input(false, title="fill in the emas")

//----ema calc
e8 = ema(close, 8)
e100 = ema(close, 100)
e200 = ema(close, 200)

//----plots. checks if the switch for the emas are on and then plots. 

ep8 = plot(ei8 and e8?e8:na, color= e8>=e100? green:red)
ep100 = plot(ei100 and e100?e100:na, color= e100>=e200? blue:purple)
ep200 = plot(ei200 and e200?e200:na, color= gray)

//---- now if i make this if statement here, then i can 

if efp
    ep8= p8
    ep100=p100
    ep200=p200
    fill(p8, p100, color=teal)
    fill(p100, p200, color=olive)
    fill(p8, p200, color=green)
```

That throws errors `"Undeclared identifier p8;..."` etc....

What am I doing wrong here?

There was another one I worked on, and that threw an error saying "fill cannot be used in local..." etc., something to that effect.

---

Edit: 9-4-19 as per baris's suggestion. But his idea turns on/off the line plots with the fills entirely, so i've tried putting the switches for the individual fills but that didn't work either.

So still I have problems coming up with a switch that will let me: 1. plot the individual emas, 2. fill the individual emas with another of choosing.

```
//@version=3
study("fill ema test")

//---input switches for the emas

ei8 = input(true, title="ema 8")
ei100 = input(true, title="ema 100")
ei200 = input(true, title="ema 200")

//----ema calc
e8 = ema(close, 8)
e100 = ema(close, 100)
e200 = ema(close, 200)

//---input switch attempts for the fills. this added to the plot will turn fills on or off but only along with the plots.  
// ef8 = input(false, title= "fill e8/e100")
// ef100 = input(false, title= "fill e100/e200")
// ef200 = input(false, title="fill e8/e200")

efp= input(true, title="fill in the emas")

//----plots. checks if the switch for the emas are on and then plots. 

ep8 = plot(ei8 and e8 and efp?e8:na, color= e8>=e100? green:red)
ep100 = plot(ei100 and e100 and efp?e100:na, color= e100>=e200? blue:purple)
ep200 = plot(ei200 and e200 and efp?e200:na, color= gray)


fill(ep8, ep100, color=teal)
fill(ep100, ep200, color=olive)
fill(ep8, ep200, color=green)
```

And doing the following will plot all the lines and fills but turn them both off individually at the same time.

```
ef8 = input(true, title= "fill e8/e100")
ef100 = input(true, title= "fill e100/e200")
ef200 = input(true, title="fill e8/e200")

// efp= input(true, title="fill in the emas")

//----plots. checks if the switch for the emas are on and then plots. 

// ep8 = plot(ei8 and e8 and efp?e8:na, color= e8>=e100? green:red)
// ep100 = plot(ei100 and e100 and efp?e100:na, color= e100>=e200? blue:purple)
// ep200 = plot(ei200 and e200 and efp?e200:na, color= gray)

ep8 = plot(ei8 and e8 and ef8?e8:na, color= e8>=e100? green:red)
ep100 = plot(ei100 and e100 and ef100?e100:na, color= e100>=e200? blue:purple)
ep200 = plot(ei200 and e200 and ef200?e200:na, color= gray)

fill(ep8, ep100, color=teal)
fill(ep100, ep200, color=olive)
fill(ep8, ep200, color=green)
```

Ideally, the lines can be turned off and on individually, and the fills can also be turned off and on individually.

Is this just some logic problem I have or a limitation of tradingview?

Answer (score 1):

The error message clearly tells you what you are doing wrong. You have not declared these variables: `p8`, `p100` and `p200`. By looking at your code, you don't need those variables, you can simply use `ep8`, `ep100` and `ep200` respectively.

```
if efp
    fill(ep8, ep100, color=teal)
    fill(ep100, ep200, color=olive)
    fill(ep8, ep200, color=green)
```

If you do that, you will get the following error:

```
line 31: Cannot use 'fill' in local scope.;
line 32: Cannot use 'fill'in local scope.; 
line 33: Cannot use 'fill' in local scope.
```

You cannot call `fill()` (and some other functions) in local scope (if-block here).

What you can do is, simply add your condition to `series` parameter of your `plot()` functions.

```
ep8 = plot(ei8 and e8 and efp?e8:na, color= e8>=e100? green:red)
ep100 = plot(ei100 and e100 and efp?e100:na, color= e100>=e200? blue:purple)
ep200 = plot(ei200 and e200 and efp?e200:na, color= gray)
```

Note the `and efp` condition.

So, both together:

```
//----plots. checks if the switch for the emas are on and then plots. 

ep8 = plot(ei8 and e8 and efp?e8:na, color= e8>=e100? green:red)
ep100 = plot(ei100 and e100 and efp?e100:na, color= e100>=e200? blue:purple)
ep200 = plot(ei200 and e200 and efp?e200:na, color= gray)

//---- now if i make this if statement here, then i can 

fill(ep8, ep100, color=teal)
fill(ep100, ep200, color=olive)
fill(ep8, ep200, color=green)
```

Comment: But I did define them inside the if statement `ep8= p8 ep100=p100 ep200=p200` i guess definition inside an "if" doesn't count?

Comment: ok, so I've tried this a few different things to make it work, but this turns off the entire plot without the fills. and if i turn the fill on it will plot them but you can't turn the fill off. i'll show what I did in my edited post.

Comment: OK, so the plot can be enabled/ disabled conditionally. But I dont see how to do the same for the fill? how can I toggle on/ off the fill() function?

Comment: @kerner1000 you can use the `display` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

```
fill(p8, p100, color=efp ? teal : na)
fill(p100, p200, color=efp ? olive : na)
fill(p8, p200, color=efp ? green : na)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally hide your fill() like this:

```
color_1 = (price_1 > price_2 ? color.new(color.green, 50) : color.new(color.red, 50))
if(hide_fill_1)
    color_1 := color.new(color.aqua, 100) // make color transparent

fill(p1, p2, color = color_1)
```